# Deselect a row depending on a value when other row is selected in UITableView Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I made an expanding **tableViewCell** and I got a default value of a variable which is **false**. If the value is **false** then **Cell** shrinks, when its **true** then **cell** expand. Problem is when a value of a **cell** is **true** I want all the other **cell** value to be **false**, which I am struggling. Here is my code below:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let content = datasource[indexPath.row]

    //Here content.expand = false by default in other class

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        print("0 row")
        content.expanded = !content.expanded

    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        print("1 row")
        content.expanded = !content.expanded

    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        print("2 row")
        content.expanded = !content.expanded
    }

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

}
```

Image of the scenario below:
[image]

I do not want two **cell** to be expanded at the same time. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** declare this variable

```
var selectedIndex: IndexPath?
```

**Next, here is your selection code:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    if(selectedIndex != indexPath){ // It's not the expanded cell

        var indicesArray = [IndexPath]()

        if(selectedIndex != nil){  //User already expanded other previous cell

            let prevExpandedContent = datasource[(selectedIndex?.row)!]

            prevExpandedContent.expanded = !prevExpandedContent.expanded

            indicesArray.append(selectedIndex!)

        }

        // Assign new expanded cell

        selectedIndex = indexPath


        let currentExpandedContent = datasource[indexPath.row]

        currentExpandedContent.expanded = !currentExpandedContent.expanded


        indicesArray.append(indexPath)

        tableView.reloadRows(at: indicesArray , with: .automatic)



    }



}
```

Hope it will simplify your requirement.